# select tds in same tr after of found td

Tags: php, curl, domdocument, domxpath

I've read through the docs and searched, but I'm still just as clueless as I started.

I'm trying to select specific elements off [this page](http://investing.money.msn.com/investments/stock-cash-flow/?symbol=mmm&stmtView=Qtr).

I know how to find the `td` with `id="Source"`, but I have no idea how to select the subsequent `td`s in the same `tr`.

Please help.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without xpath queries:

```
$xmlErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($sourceHtml);

$tr = $dom->getElementById('Source')->parentNode;

foreach($tr->childNodes as $node)
  print $node->nodeValue;

libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors($xmlErrors);
```

Comment: Yaah I have not seen `parentNode` there. I have given upvote :)